# Can you get confidence intervals for a cause-specific cumulative incidence with survfit?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, confidence-interval

I have a competing risks data set and am trying to obtain, for a specific set of explanatory variables, the cumulative incidence at a specific time and a confidence interval for the value.

Using the rotterdam dataset from the survival package as an example:

```
library(survival)
rott <- rotterdam

rott <- rott %>%
  mutate(time=pmin(dtime,rtime)) %>%
  mutate(outcome = ifelse(death==1|recur==1,1,0)) %>%
  mutate(status = ifelse(death==1,2,ifelse(recur==1,1,0)))

model <- coxph(Surv(time,as.factor(status))~hormon+age, data=rott, id=pid)

predict <- survfit(model, newdata=c(hormon=1, age=50))

summary(predict,time=2000)$pstate
```

This gives me the cumulative incidence for the competing risks at time 2000, but I can't see how to obtain a confidence interval for this.

In the non-competing risk setting for the survival I know you can use `$upper` and `$lower` but trying to find the equivalent here.

Comment: I don't think you can easily do this. The [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/survfit.coxph.html) for the `se.fit` argument to the `survfit()` method for `coxph` and `coxphm` objects state _Default is_ `TRUE` _for standard models,_ `FALSE` _for multi-state (code not yet present for that case.)_ A competing risks model is a multi-state model so this is not supported in `survfit()`. An alternative could be to bootstrap confidence intervals.

Comment: That explains why I couldn't find it. Do you know if there is a built in way to do bootstrapping?

Comment: The `flexsurv` package can bootstrap confidence intervals. See [here](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/flexsurv/html/bootci.fmsm.html). I haven't looked too closely at whether it can do exactly what you want here.

Comment: See <https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/638133/8402>.